# Modify Cron syntax in apex so that job runs every hour except 12am-1am

Tags: apex

I currently have a batch job which I am running every hour. I scheduled the job using CRON syntax in apex. My problem is that I would like to run this job everyhour except from midnight to 1am. I dont know how to write this "except" part in cron apex. This is what I have so far:

```
global static String scheduletheBatch() {
        datetime nextScheduleTime = system.now().addHours(1);
        integer minute = nextScheduleTime.minute();
        integer second = nextScheduleTime.second ();
        integer hour = nextScheduleTime.hour();
        integer year = nextScheduleTime.year(); 
        integer month = nextScheduleTime.month(); 
        integer day = nextScheduleTime.day();
        string cronvalue = second + ' ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ? ' + year;
        string jobName = 'Self Rescheduling Batch Job Scheduler ' + nextScheduleTime.format('hh:mm'); 

        BatchJobScheduler scheduler = new LPP_BatchJobScheduler();
        return system.schedule(jobName, cronvalue, scheduler);
}
```

If someone can please help then that would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't exclude things easily, but you can include many hours.

The syntax above runs a job at 7a, 12p and 3p on the hour. Just add the hours you need in there.

```
String schedule = '0 0 7,12,15 * * ?';

System.schedule('My Job', schedule, new MyClass());
```

Comment: Hello @Sebastian Kessel. If the job runs every hour, why did you put a 30 in the sceond spot? Can you please let me know?

Comment: It was the minute spot, and I forgot to edit it from the code I extracted this from. It is correct now.

Comment: Thanks! What do you think sbout this solution: where i am checking if the hour is between midnight and 1:  datetime nextScheduleTime;
        
        integer hourStart = system.now().hour();
        if(23<=hourStart && hourStart <= 01){
           nextScheduleTime = system.now().addHours(2); 
        }
        else{
            nextScheduleTime = system.now().addHours(1);
        } // rest of line same as above

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but I had the same problem and I came up with the following:

```
String timeStamp = '0 0 1-23 * * ? *';
```

The '-' special character for the cron expression allows you to do a range of hours.  So 1-23 is the equivalent of 1am through 11pm.  Midnight rolls around without this job firing, then 1am it starts over again.

Similar to Sebastian's answer, just without needing to explicitly list each hour.